# Evaluate $P(x) \bmod (x^2-x-2)$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial.
>
> If $P(x) \bmod (x+1)=0$ and $P(x) \bmod (x-2)=6$, then evaluate $P(x) \bmod (x^2-x-2)$.

My attempt:

$$P(x)=k(x)(x-2)+6=k(x)(x+1)-3(k(x)-2)$$
$$\Longrightarrow (k(x))-2) \bmod (x+1)=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \left(\dfrac{P(x)-6}{x-2}-2\right) \bmod (x+1)=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow (P(x)-2x-2) \bmod ((x+1)(x-2)) =0$$
$$\Longrightarrow P(x) \bmod (x^2-x-2) \equiv (2x+2) \bmod ((x+1)(x-2)) = (2x+2) \bmod (x^2-x-2)=2x+2 $$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The answer is correct and I follow your argument (although it seems more complicated than the way I'd do it).

Comment: @ancientmathematician thank you for comment. I have a problem in the last line. At least can you verify my last equality? $(2x+2) \mod (x^2-x-2)=2x+2$

Comment: @ancientmathematician did you find a mistake?

Comment: The answer is $(2x+2) \mod (x^2-x-2)$. This doesn't equal $2x+2$ it only equals $2x+2$ $\mod (x^2-x-2)$

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct, but here is a different way to approach it. Though not stated, I'll assume we are working in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Notice that $(x^2 - x - 2) = (x-2)(x+1)$, i.e. it is the product of the moduli in your first two congruence equations. A quick check shows that indeed these moduli, $x+1$ and $x-2$, are coprime. This should immediately make you think of **Chinese Remainder Theorem**.

Let $p(x) = x+1$ and $q(x) = x-2$. We need to find the "inverses" of these, i.e. $p^{-1}(x)$ and $q^{-1}(x)$ such that:
$$
p(x)p^{-1}(x) \equiv 1 \mod q(x), \; \; \; \; \; q(x)q^{-1}(x) \equiv 1 \mod p(x).
$$
With this, the theorem gives the solution to be:
$$
P(x) \equiv a\:q(x)q^{-1}(x) + b\:p(x)p^{-1}(x) \mod (x^2-x-2). 
$$
In this case, $a=0$ and $b=6$, so we only need to find $p^{-1}(x)$. A quick computation reveals:
$$
p^{-1}(x) = x-\frac{5}{3}
$$
as:
$$
(x+1)\Big(x-\frac{5}{3}\Big) - 1= x^2 - \frac{2}{3}x - \frac{8}{3} = (x-2)\Big(x+\frac{4}{3}\Big),
$$
i.e. $p\: p^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$. So this gives the solution,
$$
P(x) = 6(x+1)\Big(x-\frac{5}{3}\Big) = (x+1)(6x-10) = 6x^2 -4x - 10 = 6(x^2 - x - 2) + 2x+2,
$$
which is to say:
$$
P(x) \equiv 2x+2 \mod (x^2 - x -2). 
$$

Comment: Your polynomial is not an unique.

Comment: @Elementary The polynomials are unique up to the modulus

Comment: Your solution implies, we have only $P(x)=6(x^2-x-2)+2x+2$ but this is  definitely wrong.

Comment: Well I wrote it to say "if you take $p^{-1}(x) = x - 5/3$ then you end up with the following $P(x)$", which is why I wrote "this gives the solution," because indeed a different choice of $p^{-1}(x)$ yields a different $P(x)$, however they are all the same under the respective moduli. At no point did I say "we have *only* $P(x) = 6(x^2 -x -2) + 2x + 2$".

Comment: I solved my problem https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3744076/548054

Comment: @Elementary yes your solution is correct. Do you still think my solution contains errors?

Comment: Your solution may be correct.  I already upvoted.  But I will not say that it is a perfect answer.

Comment: @Elementary that's fine, I am just curious how I can improve my answer, or what you feel is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

In as simple a case as this we can just proceed this way.

We have $P(x)= ax+b \mod (x^2-x-2)$ for some $a,b$.

That is $P(x)=ax+b+ q(x)(x+1)(x-2)$.

Putting $x=-1$ and $x=2$ gives us $-a+b=0$ and $2a+b=6$.

Hence $a=b=2$.

But in general I'd suggest that the Extended Chinese Remainder Algorithm is the way to go.