# Is it possible to prove that $P(x)$ is unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial.
>
> If $P(x) \bmod (x+1)=0$ and $P(x) \bmod (x-2)=6$, then here are my questions:

> i) What is the general form of the $P(x)$ ?
>
> ii) What is the minimal degree of polynomial for $P(x)$ ?
>
> iii) Is the polynomial $P(x)$ unique? Can we prove this uniqueness?

I have an example for $P(x)$.

$$P(x)=
6x^2-4x-10$$

Can we prove that, this polynomial is unique?

Comment: Your second condition means nothing but $P(2)=6$. So, $P$ is non-constant and has minimum degree $1$ and is of the general form $P(x) = (x+1)r(x)$ with $r(2) = 2$.

Comment: @trancelocation What is the $r(2)$

Comment: The value of the polynomial $r(x)$ at $x=2$ has to be equal to $2$: $r(2) = 2$. Because $P(2)=(2+1)\cdot r(2) = 6$.

Comment: So, $r(x)$ can be any polynomial with $r(2) = 2$.

Comment: @trancelocation But this is not an explicit formula.

Comment: @Elementary:  You should probably give your Question more thought.  What kind of polynomial is $P(x)$?  What, in addition to your "example for $P(x)$" would constitute a "general form" in an "explicit formula"?  Having been around the site for awhile, I think it best to encourage you to put a little more effort into asking and understanding this problem.

Comment: @hardmath I found the explicit formula myself right now.  without any modular restrictions.

Comment: @Elementary: What do you mean by "explicit"?

Comment: @trancelocation  for example, formula for the quadratic equation.

Comment: Already for the quadratic case there are infinitely many polynomials: For $b \neq 2$ you have: $P(x) = 2\frac{x-b}{2-b}(x+1)$. Obviously far from being unique.

Comment: @trancelocation You didnt understand me. I mean general quadratic formula (as an explicit formula). I will answer to my question now. I prepare.

Comment: @Elementary : Your comment "But this is not an explicit formula." wrt. my proposed general formula (which is explicit btw.) truly needs clarification :-)

Comment: @trancelocation you can check my answer now.

Comment: @hardmath  I finished my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My work:

$$\begin{cases} P(x)=k_1(x)(x+1) \\ P(x)=k_2(x)(x-2)+6 \end{cases} \Longrightarrow (x+1)k_1(x)=k_2(x)(x-2)+6 ​ \Longrightarrow (x+1)k_1(x)=k_2(x)(x+1)-3(k_2(x)-2) \Longrightarrow (k_2(x)-2) \mod (x+1)=0 \Longrightarrow k_2(x)=g(x)(x+1)+2 \\ \\ k_1(x)= \dfrac{k_2(x)(x-2)+6}{x+1} =\dfrac{(g(x)(x+1)+2) \times (x+1)+2)(x-2)+6}{x+1}=\dfrac{x(x+1)g(x)-2g(x)(x+1)+2x+2}{x+1}=\dfrac{(x+1)(xg(x)-2g(x)+2)}{x+1}=xg(x)-2g(x)+2=g(x)(x-2)+2 \\ P(x)=(x+1)(xg(x)-2g(x)+2)=g(x)x^2-x(g(x)-2)-2g(x)+2$$

$$\color{red}{\boxed{{P(x)=g(x)x^2-x(g(x)-2)-2g(x)+2}}}$$
here, $g(x)$ is an any polynomial.

$$ \color{blue}{\begin{cases} P(x)=g(x)x^2-x(g(x)-2)-2g(x)+2 \\ g(x)=0 \end{cases} \Longrightarrow P(x)=2x+2}$$

Random example:
$$\color{green}{\begin{cases} P(x)=g(x)x^2-x(g(x)-2)-2g(x)+2 \\ g(x)=x^2-x+1 \end{cases} \Longrightarrow P(x)=x^4-2x^3+3x}$$

Comment: You could have had this quicker:
From my above comments we have $P(x) = (x+1)r(x)$ with $r(2) = 2$. The last condition can be rewritten as $r(x) = g(x)(x-2)+2$. This gives exactly your formula. Neverthless +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
$$General \;\; form\;\; of \;\; P(x)$$
By hypothesis
$$P(x)=(x+1)Q(x)$$
$$P(x)=6+(x-2)R(x)$$
with $$d°(Q)=d°(R)=d°(P)-1$$
and
$$d°(P(x))\ge 1$$

$$Minimal \;\; degree \;\;and \;\;Uniqueness$$

Assume $P(x)=a(x+1)$.

then
$R(x)=b$ with
$$a(x+1)=6+b(x-2)=bx+6-2b$$
thus
$$a=b \text{ and } a=6-2b$$
So $$a=b=2$$
and
$$P(x)=2(x+1)=6+2(x-2)$$

The minimal degree is $ 1$ and the unique solution is
$$\boxed{P(x)=2x+2}$$

Remark.

The polynome $6x^2-4x-10$ you found is the case where  $ Q(x)=(3x-5)$.

Comment: But I have 3 questions..

Comment: @Elementary I gave three answers : 1- the general form .2- the minimum degree. 3- the uniqueness.

Comment: What is the general form?

Comment: @Elementary The two first lines of my answer.

Comment: This is not a general form. We have unknown polynomials

Comment: @Elementary That's why it is general.

Comment: I was looking for $P(x)$ in one line .explicit formula

Comment: I upvoted your answer. But, your answer doesnt provide the explicit formula.

Comment: @Elementary You can check easily that the polynom $2(x+1)$ satisfies your conditions.

Comment: You can check my answer.